# how to remove a null value from session cart dictionary in django

Tags: python, django, django-views

here is my views.py logic to add product in session cart

```
def index(request):
    categoryID= request.GET.get('category')
    product= request.POST.get('product')
    cart=request.session.get('cart')
    
    if cart:
        quantity=cart.get(product)
        if quantity:
            cart[product]=quantity+1
        else:
            cart[product]=1

        cart['product']=1
    else:
        cart['product']= 1
    request.session['cart']=cart
    print(cart)
    print(product)
    category=Category.get_all_categories()
    if categoryID:
        products = Product.get_all_products_by_id(categoryID)
    else:
        products=Product.get_all_products()
    prddata={
        'product' : products,
        'cat': category,
    }
    return render(request,'index.html',prddata)
```

I have added two product in cart
but when I print cart in terminal

```
{'product': 1, '1': 1, '2': 4, 'null': 1}
2
[06/Nov/2021 01:10:25] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 13104
```

this null is being added I don't know how. How to prevent this or remove it from cart?
please help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any code in here that adds the `'null'` value to the cart, except when product is `'null'`. To remove it, you can add the following code to your function:

```py
if 'null' in list(cart.keys()):
    del cart['null']
```

Also, the line `cart['product']=1` is executed in any path, so you can remove the else clause and place it out of any if statement, like the following.

```py
if cart:
    quantity=cart.get(product)
    if quantity:
        cart[product]=quantity+1
    else:
        cart[product]=1
cart['product']=1
```